# Read Arabic file contents using string in c++

Tags: c++, string, file, ansi

I have a text file (ansi encoding) that contains an arabic contents and I have read it using c++ as:

```
ifstream ifs(file.GetFileName());
std::string content((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs)),          std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

unfortunately the content variable holds encrypted strings (which must be in arabic lang) i.e:

```
121101  ÇáÒÈæä ßãÇá
121102  ÇáÒÈæä ÓÚíÏ
121103  ÇáÒÈæä ÚãÇÑ
```

any solution???

Thanks :)

Comment: did you tried with std::wstring?

Comment: What do you mean by "ansi encoding"? Do you mean extended ASCII? What platform (operating system) are you targeting? Windows? What codepage and locale settings do you have? I don't think the contents is encrypted, just that the encoding is not what you think it is. Maybe it's UTF-8? Also, how are you displaying the contents of the file? Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: There is no such thing as "extended ASCII". Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII

Comment: I mean I have saved my file using notepad as ansi (not UTF8, nor Unicode).
My OS is Windows, and the local settings is supporting Arabic.
I have add the content var to watch window in visual studio and see the value like this 'ÇáÒÈæä ßãÇá' !!!!